# Puppet File and Service Comands Not Running on Client

Tags: puppet

Solved!!

So here is the answer - I had `sites.pp` not `site.pp` Thanks @Shane Madden

debug: importing '/etc/puppet/manifests/nodes.pp' in environment production

If you are including nodes.pp in your site.pp should show up in --debug logging.

I am having a problem diagnosing a base puppet master / client issue. The puppet master is running as another server name and is set correctly in /etc/puppet/puppet.conf file.  Both file and service command are not functioning on the client. No errors any where in debug mode.

Here is a breakdown:

1. Client and master are talking correctly.  I run both in --no-daemonize --debug and they are chatting nicely - no errors or warnings.
2. If I do a `puppet apply site.pp` on the client side it work.  I am removing the `node` parens.
3. The puppet file on the server parses correctly.
4. I worked around the "Could not retrieve fact fqdn" error by setting the hostname in the /etc/hosts file.

It appears that the client is not picking up the site.pp node name, and I have used default. Or for some reason the puppet command is not running.

I have tried doing a simple file sync and a service command, and both are not running correct.

The debug output on the master show's it received the report from the client.

How do I get more debugging information beside `--debug`.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Where's the `site.pp` located, and is your master throwing any errors about being unable to load it?  Does your client system have anything in its cached catalog at `/var/lib/puppet/client_data/catalog`?

Comment: no errors that I can see. Ah typo I had a typo ... sites.pp not site.pp ... please answer the question :)

Comment: wow ... typos are my bane :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the client isn't loading the catalog as expected, a few things to check:

- Make sure the catalog the client is getting makes sense - it should be in `$vardir/client_data/catalog`.
- Make sure during the run the client isn't using the cached catalog for some reason - usually this is when the master has an error or is not accessible.
- Verify which environment your node is using, if you have multiple.
- If changes to the files aren't being picked up, make sure they're being read properly - adding an `err('this ran')` will log the message on the master during catalog generation.